# Can the OP see my edit that needs peer review?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

OP asked a long question, I fixed some typos. My reputation is still low so it needs peer-review. Can OP see my edits yet?

The problem is I fixed typos, but there's a shady part where I know they made a mistake but I don't know for sure what they meant.

I told them so they edit their post. Will my edit be taken into account? Or will I have to fix the same typos again? (Assuming it didn't get peer-reviewed at the time OP edited their post.)

Comment: So you suggested an edit, and commented afterwards? Could you leave a link to the post in question?

Comment: @M.A.R. Yes, I fixed "the are" to "they are", stuff that I'm 100% sure of, but they used "responsible" as a noun and I'm not that eager to fix it without asking them. [Here's](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/118730/when-something-is-wrong-at-the-beginning-of-a-series-of-some-related-actions) the question. By the way my edit was accepted in no time, but I'm still curious about the situation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yep, OPs can always see and approve/reject edits made on their posts, even if they have one rep. They even get notifications that edits were suggested on their post. Furthermore, their decision on their post is binding, like a moderator's decision, which means that if they click "approve", the edit would be approved immediately, whether or not the necessary number of votes have been given in favor of approving.

They're usually not the reviewers of edits on their post though, since anyone with more than 2,000 rep can review suggested edits.

That post's [timeline](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/118730/timeline) indicates that you suggested an edit, which was approved by two reviewers. [Here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/52423)'s a link to your edit. You did the thing everyone would normally do. Comment and ask for a bit of clarification, and improve the post by an edit. There's not more to be done.